# Why am I getting a NullPointerException when trying to 'invoke virtual method SearchView.setOnQueryListener'?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In my fragment I have a simple SearchView and a RecyclerView. I want to be able to filter the items of this recycler view with this simple code.

```
var mContext: Context? = null
    
        var searchList: ArrayList<Note> = ArrayList<Note>()
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            val DB = NotesDB.getAppDB(mContext!!)
    
            var notesList: ArrayList<Note>? = ArrayList()
    
            runBlocking {
                launch {
                    notesList!!.addAll(DB!!.noteDao().getAll())
                    searchList.addAll(notesList)
                }
            }
    
            var layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(mContext, 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    
            var adapter = NoteAdapter(mContext!!, searchList!!)
            homeRecycler?.layoutManager = layoutManager
            homeRecycler?.adapter = adapter
    
            searchBar.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                    return true
                }
    
                override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                    if (newText!!.isNotEmpty()){
                        searchList.clear()
                        var search = newText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).trim()
    
                        for(note in notesList!!){
                            if (note.name.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).trim().contains(search)){
                                searchList.add(note)
                            }
                            searchRecycler.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }
                    } else{
                        searchList.clear()
                        searchList.addAll(notesList!!)
                        searchRecycler.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                    return true
                }
    
            })
    
    
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
        }
    
        override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
            super.onAttach(context)
            mContext = context
        }
    }
```

However, I always end up getting this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.byteseb.zennotes.fragments.SearchFragment.onCreateView(SearchFragment.kt:52)
```

I really do not know why does this happen, as *searchBar* is not null (a reference to the searchView that I have on the layout file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The searchBar view is not created when running `setOnQueryTextListener()`, hence the null pointer exception. you can either move all the code (except inflating the layout) from `onCreateView` to `onViewCreated` which execute after the view is created, or you can inflate the layout before calling the function like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
         val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
         //skip
         view.searchBar.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
         //skip
         }
         return view
}
```